# Plotting half circles in R

Tags: r, plot, geometry

I'm trying to plot half circles using R. My final aim is to draw a circle, divided in the middle by color. The only way I have found yet is to draw two half-circles with different colors.
So I have created my own functions:

```
upper.half.circle <- function(x,y,r,nsteps=100,...){  
  rs <- seq(0,pi,len=nsteps) 
  xc <- x+r*cos(rs) 
  yc <- y+r*sin(rs) 
  polygon(xc,yc,...) 
} 

lower.half.circle <- function(x,y,r,nsteps=100,...){ 
  rs <- seq(0,pi,len=nsteps) 
  xc <- x-r*cos(rs) 
  yc <- y-r*sin(rs) 
  polygon(xc,yc,...) 
}
```

However, for some reason my half-circles end up more like half-ellipses. For example, try running:

```
plot(1, type="n",axes=F,xlab="", ylab="",xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,200))
upper.half.circle(15,170,10,nsteps=1000,col='red')
```

Does anyone know why I'm having this trouble, or alternatively, knows of a better way to do what I want?
Thanks!

Comment: What type of plot are we trying to make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the default aspect ratio is not 1:1.

To fix this, set `asp=1` in `plot`:

[image: fixed circle]

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693558/how-to-define-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-scatter-plot) Q & A. You could have sniffed out this was the case by turning on the axes and x/y labels.

Answer (score 4):

If using the grid package would be also an opportunity for you, there is a much simpler solution:

```
library(grid)
vp <- viewport(width=0.5, height=0.5, clip  = "on")
grid.circle(0.5,0,r=0.5, gp = gpar(fill = 'red'), vp = vp)
```

This creates a viewport with clipping, i.e., an appropriate positioning of the filled circle creates a half circle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your half circles to an existing plot (and therefore cannot control the aspect ratio directly) then one option for this specific case is to use the `floating.pie` function from the plotrix package.

A more general tool for creating custom symbols and adding them to plots (with the symbols having a different aspect ratio from the overall plot) is to use the `my.symbols` function from the TeachingDemos package.