# Multicolored points in plot

Tags: r, colors, points

I'd like to add points that are multicoloured dots, with one half in blue for ex. and one half in red. If possible, I'd like to be able to do it with more than 2 colors, for example 4 quarters, each with a color.
Is that at all possible?

I know I can superimpose several dots of different sizes, each with a color, resulting in a concentric multicolored dot. But this is not what I am after.

For context, I am using these points for cities in a map.
Here is a small example, with each city having a unicolored dot. But I would like each city to have a dot that has two halves, each one with a color.

```
require(ggmap);

citiesnames=c("Madrid","Toledo","Valencia","Granada")

cities=str_c(citiesnames,"Spain",sep=", ");
geo=geocode(cities);
lon=geo$lon;
lat=geo$lat;
coord=mapproject(lon, lat,proj="mercator");

map("world","Spain",fill=T,col="ivory",proj="mercator");

points(coord$x[1], coord$y[1], pch=16, cex=1.2, col="black")
points(coord$x[2],coord$y[2], pch=16, cex=1.2, col="red")
points(coord$x[3], coord$y[3], pch=16, cex=1.2, col="blue")
points(coord$x[4], coord$y[4], pch=16, cex=1.2, col="green4")
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may use `col = discrete_variable` in base graphics. But you need to provide more information and perhaps a sample code of what you got.

Comment: @Masoud I don't want points of different colors depending on a value. I want points that have two halves, each one with a color. I don't think it is a duplicate of the question you mention.

Comment: @student I've added a code example. Also what do you mean by col=discrete_variable ?

Comment: @Lamia In that case, I would try adding two points on the graph for the same data-point and change the shapes to have two half-circles and color them differently. Have not done that in R ever. Usually I need to do these kind of tasks in ArcMap.

Comment: @Masoud I am not aware of a half-circle shape. Here are the shapes available in base: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/pchsymbols.php

Comment: @Lamia I guess this is exactly what you want to do. read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538534/plotting-half-circles-in-r

Comment: @Lamia I mean you may do something like this `points(coord$x, coord$y, pch = 16, cex = 1.2, col = 1:4)`. This will produce all four dots you have above and can scale.

Comment: I ended up using the floating.pie function from the plotrix package mentioned in one of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538534/plotting-half-circles-in-r. Its actual purpose is to draw pie charts within a plot, but it works for what I wanted to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538534/plotting-half-circles-in-r) for doing what you want. For documentation purposes I add an answer which resolve the issue:

You can add two half circles (pie charts) to your graph using these two functions:

```
  upper.half.circle <- function(x,y,r,nsteps=100,...){  
    rs <- seq(0,pi,len=nsteps) 
    xc <- x+r*cos(rs) 
    yc <- y+r*sin(rs) 
    polygon(xc,yc,...) 
  } 

  lower.half.circle <- function(x,y,r,nsteps=100,...){ 
    rs <- seq(0,pi,len=nsteps) 
    xc <- x-r*cos(rs) 
    yc <- y-r*sin(rs) 
    polygon(xc,yc,...) 
  }
```

Later when you are piloting you should set `asp = 1` to get the half-circles.

```
   plot(1, type="n",axes=F,xlab="", ylab="",xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,200), asp = 1)
   upper.half.circle(15,170,10,nsteps=1000,col='red')
   lower.half.circle(15,170,10,nsteps=1000,col='blue')
```

Here's the result of this code:

[image]

You can later edit the fictions for getting quarters or whatever you need.