# R: How to make the x and y axis be the same length?

Tags: r, plot, axis

R always makes x axis longer compared to the y axis, even if they both have the same limits. Is there an option to control the length of the axis?

```
plot(0:100,0:100)
```

[image]

I need it to be a square.

Comment: there is also`par(pty="s")` (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693558/how-to-define-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-scatter-plot)

Comment: If you save your plots with equal height and width, they'll also end up square: `png('~/Desktop/Rplot.png'); plot(0:100, 0:100); dev.off()` (`png` default height and width are both 480px.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, at least if you are using base graphics. The asp argument should be set to 1:

```
plot(0:100,0:100, asp=1)   # see ?plot.default
```

The duplicate that Ben found also has

```
plot(0:100,0:100, pty="s")
```

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693558/how-to-define-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-scatter-plot?lq=1 ?

Comment: Yeah. I didn't remember my prior answer. And didn't follow user65250's link.