# Converting a plot to a square plot

Tags: r, plot

I have two ROC curves are plotted in one plot. How can I convert the plot to a square plot ? And how can I give the first curve a green colour and the second curve a red colour? 
Here is a producible example:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1) 
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels )
pred2 <- prediction(abs(ROCR.simple$predictions + 
                        rnorm(length(ROCR.simple$predictions), 0, 0.1)), 
                ROCR.simple$labels)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr" )
perf2 <- performance(pred2, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf)
plot(perf2, add = TRUE)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693558/how-to-define-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-scatter-plot#8762825)?

Comment: Hey @Axeman , this has solved the problem, but how can I add colour to the curves to depreciate them ?

Comment: That would be a whole different question.

Comment: @Joe: try plot(perf2, add = TRUE, col = "green")