# How to plot based on a wildcard

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
A 2 3 LOGIC:A
B 3  3 LOGIC:B
C 2 2 COMBO:A

plot(Data$V2[Data$V4 == "LOGIC:A"], DATA$V3[Data$V4 == "LOGIC:A"])
```

However I want to plot whenever the column 4 is LOGIC, when I provide "LOGIC" inside the plot command it should plot both "LOGIC:A" and "LOGIC:B". Right now it only accepts the exact column 4 value. Can I use wildcards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Data` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end this will plot those rows for which V4 contains the substring `LOGIC` using the character after the colon to represent the point.  If you want all points to be represented by the same character omit the `pch` argument from `plot`.

```
plot(V3 ~ V2, Data, subset = grep("LOGIC", V4),  pch = sub("LOGIC:", "", V4))
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- "A 2 3 LOGIC:A
B 3  3 LOGIC:B
C 2 2 COMBO:A"
Data <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I also plot columns 2 vs 3 for all unique Column 4 and return a legend which colorizes based on what we have in column 4? for example all LOGIC:A occurences are colored blue , all COMBO:A occurences are plotted red etc.. Is this possible for R to do it automatically? Say we don't know how many unique column 4 keys we have

Comment: Best to switch to ggplot2 to get automatic legends. `library(ggplot2); ggplot(Data, aes(V2, V3, col = V4)) + geom_point()`

Comment: Thanks for the help. possibly a final question. Can you plot a 45 degree like abline(0,1) in R? And what exactly does the geom_point command do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693558/how-to-define-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-scatter-plot

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grepl` to find occurrences of your string.

```
x <- c("LOGIC: A", "COMBO: B")
x[grepl("LOGIC", x)]
[1] "LOGIC: A"
```